# Debugger.Launch() on Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, debug, visual-studio-2017, debugger

I have Visual Studio Professional 2017 Version 15.8.2, I'm trying to use Debugger.Launch() but I can't see VS2017 on the list of possible debuggers in the Visual Studio Just-In-Time Debugger window.

I found is a bug of VS2017 that was corrected, but it's not working to me. Any idea or suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This a 32-bit for 64-bit application?  What programming language is it written n?

Comment: It's an Windows Service App, C#

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was that the "Just-In-Time debugger" was not activated by default. I activate it and run the Visual Studio 2017 as Administrator and it's working.

1.Click on modify button:

[image]

[image]

Comment: whyyyyyyyyyyyy is this not installed by default?!?  Much appreciated @gemr1423